Ionisation isomerism in coordination compounds
Why can't the coordination number of the central atom change in case of ionisation isomerism?
Even if coordination number changes, it would still fit the definition of isomerism right?
For example, would two complexes of Ni2+ that have the same ligand and counterion groups, but with coordination numbers 4 and 6 be considered ionisation isomers, or even any isomers?
$\ce{[NiL4X2]} \ \text{ and } \ \ce{[NiL4]X2}$
In all sources online, it is said that coordination number cannot change.

If you change the coordination number (C.N.) of the central metallic atom (CMA), the compounds cannot be considered isomers. According to the IUPAC Gold Book an isomer is:

One of several species (or molecular entities) that have the same atomic composition (molecular formula) but different line formulae or different stereochemical formulae and hence different physical and/or chemical properties.
Sources:

PAC, 1994, 66, 1077. (Glossary of terms used in physical organic chemistry (IUPAC Recommendations 1994)) on page 1129
PAC, 1996, 68, 2193. (Basic terminology of stereochemistry (IUPAC Recommendations 1996)) on page 2210


Now, considering your example of two $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ complexes:
$$\ce{[NiL4]X2} \ \text{ and } \ \ce{[NiL6]X2}$$
These two complexes, regardless of the ligands and counterions, cannot be considered isomers, let alone ionisation isomers. This is because the first complex has 4 ligands coordinating with the metal, while the second has 6 ligands. In simpler terms, they have different stoichiometric ratios and atomic compositions, which disqualifies them from being isomers.
For complexes to be ionisation isomers, they must have different ligands attached to the CMA while maintaining the same stoichiometric ratios. For example:
$$\ce{[Co(NH3)5Br]SO4} \ \text{ and } \ \ce{[Co(NH3)5SO4]Br}$$
These two complexes are indeed ionisation isomers because:

They have the same stoichiometric ratios.
They dissociate to give different complexes with different structures:$$\ce{[Co(NH3)5Br]SO4 -> [Co(NH3)5Br]^{2+} + SO4^2-}$$ $$\ce{[Co(NH3)5SO4]Br -> [Co(NH3)5SO4]^{+} + Br-}$$

Please note that if these complexes had different coordination numbers, they would no longer be considered isomers.
EDIT:
I had misinterpreted the question. The line of reasoning however, is the same with a slight modification.
Consider:
$$\ce{[NiL4X2]} \ \text{and} \ \ce{[NiL4]X2}$$
Those two can be considered isomers by the IUPAC definition if we analise only the brute formula without knowing the structure.
On the other hand they cannot be ionisation-isomers because upon dissociation, the first complex remains unchanged because there are no counterions, while the second gives:
$$\ce{[NiL4]X2 -> [NiL4]^2+ + 2X-}$$
Thus the real complex in solution for CN=4 has indeed a different structure with respect to the first one, and it is not possible to consider them ionization-isomers in the classical sense.
EDIT 2:
Upon an extensive search, I did not find the specific snippet of book I was planning to quote. However, re-reading the chemlibretext  page:

Ionization isomers occur when a ligand that is bound to the metal center exchanges places with an anion or neutral molecule that was originally outside the coordination complex. The geometry of the central metal ion and the identity of other ligands are identical.

Which implies two things: 1) Ionization Isomerism is bound to the actual exchange of ions between the coordination inner shell. 2) For this reason, the isomerism in question is strictly related to the conservation of molecular geometry or at least of the Coordination Number. This implies automatically that $\ce{[NiL4X2]}$ and $\ce{[NiL4]X2}$ cannot be ionization isomers due to the fact that the first does not exchange a ligand with an outer ion or molecule, but in fact they are two distinct species.
They could be considered isomers only by brute formula. Keep in mind, though that in solution, there are no isomeric species due to the ionization, while in the solid phase, isomerism loses its meaning due to the periodic nature of the crystalline lattices.
References from chemlibretext:

Petrucci, Harwood, Herring, and Madura. General Chemistry: Principles and Modern Applications: Ninth Edition. New Jersey: Pearson, 2007.
Atkins, Peter, and Loretta Jones. Chemical Principles: The Quest for Insight: Fourth Edition. W. H. Freeman and Company, 2008. Print.


But why should they have the same structure to be isomers? From what I know, the only condition for isomerism is to have same formula.

Yeah, but in solution you have ions and solvated molecules: The counterions do not count. Also consider that the first complex you wrote is not possible to dissociate also. Thus they are "isomers" if you consider the brute formula but the real complexes (the dissociated ones) are not isomers

So, you could, even if I think it is a bit improper, consider them isomers. They are not Ionisation isomers (the first cannot ionise at all).

I would like to add that there are a number of possible isomerisms in inorganic chem, this one is a bit borderline and most authors probably cathegorize the isomerisms based on the actual complex and not their ionic salt form (ionic compounds, even with complex ions involved, are usually considered as 3D lattices and the concept of molecule is less well defined).

I think your question was worth discussing though, as it is a bit ambigous. It all boils down to the definition of ionisation isomers, which involves dissotiation. To have dissotiation you need counterions and with different CN, at least in this case, it is not possible to have it.

+1, but could you cite some reliable sources supporting your comments?

sure, I'll Search for some sources, I'm pretty sure I've read those things in an official Handbook.

Got any references?

I've been swamped in the office, I'll search this  (Italy GMT)

Thanks, no problem. Whenever you are free...

So, what I get is that technically they are isomers, but not ionisation isomers. They are just isomers with no special name. Is that correct?

Yes, this would be my take on the matter, and also the common one, according to IUPAC.

Thank you very much!
